# Why "foreach" creates a delay in discord.js between interactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm new to javascript programming.
I have a bot on the discord, and one of its commands is to silence everyone in a call, but when the command is called it silences five users, creates a delay and then immediately silences the rest of the users
How can I remove this delay and why does it happen

This the command´s code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
 if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
  return message.channel.send("You don't have this permission!");

 let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
  (role) => role.name === ' Sshhhhhhh'
 );

 let channel = message.member.voice.channel;

 let user = message.author;

 if (args[0] === 'all') {
  channel.members.forEach(function(guildMember, guildMemberId) {
   guildMember.roles.add(muteRole.id);
  });
  message.delete().catch((O_o) => {});
  message.channel.send(`${user.username} silenced everyone.`);
  return;
 } else if (args[0] == null) {
  message.delete().catch((O_o) => {});
  message.channel.send(`${user.username} is silent.`);
  message.member.roles.add(muteRole.id);
  return;
 }

 let person = message.guild.member(
  message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1])
 );

 if (!person) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find that member");
 else {
  message.delete().catch((O_o) => {});
  message.channel.send(`${user.username} silenced ${person}.`);
  person.roles.add(muteRole.id);
 }
};
```

The command that silences everyone is on lines 14 and 15

```js
channel.members.forEach(function(guildMember, guildMemberId) {
 guildMember.roles.add(muteRole.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by rate limits on discord API requests (as seen [here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#header-format)). The `foreach` loop itself is not the cause of the delay, but rather discord.js itself intentionally causes a delay every 5 requests, which is why your mute roles are being added in bursts of 5.

You can't really bypass this limitation because it is built-in to the discord API itself, and the delay is built-in to discord.js as well. Bypassing this limitation would be considered abuse. You could, however, use `setTimeout` to set a small delay between each request so that the delay between every 5 requests is less noticeable.

Here is a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55792866/6901876), which is about the same rate limits but on message edits instead of adding roles.

Comment: Hi, I did some more research and redid the code. [Here is the new code](https://imgur.com/tHa46aG)