# Discord bot - delay when sending messages

Tags: java, discord-jda

java/jda beginner here. My discord bot has a couple of commands where it needs to send a lot of messages (e.g. !commandList leads to ~10 messages). However, it can't seem to send them all at once. It always sends around 5 in a row with little to no delay, then stops for 1-2 seconds, rinse and repeat. Is there any way to get rid of this?

(method used to send messages is `channel.sendMessage(String text).queue();` btw)

Comment: Is there a rate limit on the channel itself preventing the bot from sending too many messages?

Comment: @Nexevis no channels in the server are set to slowmode or the like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot editing messages too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781980/discord-bot-editing-messages-too-slow).  The top answer here explains the API has a limit of 5 messages per request.

Comment: You could use Embeds to send all the Text at once or Webhooks if it needs to be in the default text format